# two type variable in type script

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function parameter which accepts two types: `string | string[]`. I am using this parameter for a toaster service which accepts only the `string` type, so when I am using `join(' ')` I have got an error: `Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'. Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string'.` and can't compile the application.

```
showToaster(msg: string, customClass: string | string[]) {
        let cstmClass: any;

        switch (typeof customClass) {
            case 'string':
                cstmClass = customClass;
                break;
            case 'object':
                cstmClass = customClass.join(' ');
                break;
        }

        this.toastrService.show(msg, null, {
            toastClass: cstmClass,
            timeOut: 3500
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to determine the type:

```
if(Array.isArray(customClass)) {
    cstmClass = customClass.join(' ');
}
else {
    cstmClass = customClass;
}
```

The reason for the compile array is that the `|` option only exposes properties and methods shared by both types. The reason checking if the type is an `object` does not work is because `object` does not have the `join` method.

Comment: only one improvement: Array.isArray(customClass) ? cstmClass = customClass.join(' ') : cstmClass = customClass;

Comment: You can even improve this further to: `var cstmClass = Array.isArray(customClass) ? customClass.join(' ') : customClass;`